# Hi, I am trying to learn Selenium automation and getting this error : Unable to initialize main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG

Tags: java, selenium

[Screenshot of the error and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSOxo.png)

Getting error while trying to run the given code in screenshot :

Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNGException